# Calling javascript script from html

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript file like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("my controller");
});
```

I have an HTML file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/generateLineupController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

for the love of all things holy why in the world would the alert not show? I get a 200 on GET for the javascript file, so it's loading.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a `node.js` tag on this question? It's distracting me from answering your question because I'm waiting to hear about how node is involved :)

Comment: yeah, crap, I am using browserify to load node modules, I thought I might take this question in that direction, but I can remove the tag

Comment: I copied the code as it is (now ;)) in this question and got the alert. Are there other scripts being loaded, or some kind of NoScript-type plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(document).ready(...)` indicates that you are trying to use jQuery, but you aren't loading jQuery in your page. Check your console log; you will see the errors there.

Also, there's no need to load the script twice with two `<script>` tags; just load it once.

Comment: thanks Ed please see my edits, the missing jquery library is not the problem (nor was the double loading of the script).

Comment: Are you running this on a server? Or are you just opening the doc in a browser with a local file path for a URL? If the latter, the relative `src` will cause problems. Also, are you sure you haven't checked `don't show any more alerts for this page` or anything similar in your browser?

Comment: it works, when I ran the one file alone, it wasn't pulling in my javascript file. The problem I have has to do with browserify. oh well.

Answer (score 4):

Several problems here.

1. You're trying to load the script twice for some reason. Don't do that. Load it in `<head>`, *or* at the end of `<body>`, but not both.
2. You're trying to use jQuery syntax (`$(...)`), but you haven't loaded the jQuery library. You'll need that.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the jquery library for my OP, but I have it my actual code, and that's not the problem